# how to display image in CListView yii framework

Tags: php, image, yii

how to display image for a particular record???
my _view.php file is

```
<div class="view">

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('id')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id), array('view', 'id'=>$data->id)); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('name')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->name); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('product')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->product); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('category')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->category); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('image')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->image);

 ?>
<br />
```

I want to display images for each record on CListView...
I qble to display image in CDetailView but i dont know how to display image in CListView....

help me please..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [**CHtml** s image](http://yiiapi.com/CHtml#image-detail)

> Generates an image tag.
>
> > public static string image(string $src, string $alt='', array $htmlOptions=array ( ))

Update:

```
 <?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl."/images/".$model->image.$data->image,$data->im‌​age , array(
      'style' => 'max-height:40px',// set all sorts of styles here
      'class' => 'someClass',
 )); ?>
```

Comment: can you please provide me an example for that?

Comment: it might be like this echo **CHtml::image(ImageURL,$data->image,$data->image);** how to pass image URL??

Comment: I got it as--- `<?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl."/images/".$model->image.$data->image,$data->image); ?>` **Thank you so much for instant help**

Comment: it displays images in original size.. is there any fine way to display all images in fixed size?? or any extension to display in a fine UI???

Comment: yes you can use htmlOptions as an array and have style for that image and set max-height or max-width for that